# how to suppress move command result in windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I have been using the below command to move file from one folder to another using windows' command prompt.

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>move C:\Windows\System32\savestp.txt MILIData\ >nul`

`The system cannot find the file specified.`

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>`

How to suppress this error message.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>move C:\Windows\System32\savestp.txt MILIData\ >nul 2>&1
```

Explanation:

The command:

```
move
```

First parameter:

```
C:\Windows\System32\savestp.txt
```

Second parameter:

```
MILIData\
```

Redirecting the output stream to a file (in this case nul):

```
>nul
```

This is the short form and could also be written as (redirect the stream number #1)

```
1>nul
```

What you want is to also redirect the error stream (stream number #2).
In this case, you simply want to redirect #2 to the same direction as #1:

```
2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `>nul` to hide the result of a command.

Use `2>nul` to hide the errors.

`C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>move C:\Windows\System32\savestp.txt MILIData\ >nul 2>nul`